# Reading from serial port in C, having problems with ReadFile maybe?

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port, readfile

Well I've been at this program for maybe four hours.  I've been trying to create a little program to read what my arduino Uno is spitting out through the serial port.

What I find odd is that the program works only AFTER I've launched the arduino IDE's built in serial monitor. Perhaps this is an issue with initializing the port correctly?

If someone could help me out it'd be much appreciated.  The program seems to hang during ReadFile, so maybe there's an issue with permissions...

`#include Windows.h>
    #include stdio.h>
    #include tchar.h>//Removed to allow for stackoverflow format
    void printCommState(DCB d);

int main() {
    DCB dcb = { 0 };
    HANDLE hPort;
    BOOL success;
    TCHAR *commPort = TEXT("COM3");
    char buffer[40] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    DWORD dwBytesWrite = 0;
    int l;
    /*COMMTIMEOUTS cTimeOut;
    cTimeOut.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    cTimeOut.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    cTimeOut.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    cTimeOut.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    cTimeOut.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;*/
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;//Found on microsofts website
    dcb.ByteSize = DATABITS_8;// standardized number?
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;// found in comp management
    dcb.StopBits = 1;
    /*dcb.fBinary = 1;
    dcb.fDtrControl = 1;
    dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = 1;
    dcb.fRtsControl = 1;
    dcb.XonLim = 2048;
    dcb.XoffLim = 512;
    dcb.XoffChar = 2;*/
    //dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;//maybe unnecessary?

    printCommState(dcb);

    hPort = CreateFile(commPort, // This comm port is defined by TCHAR so that we can use TEXT() LPFILENAME
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,//DesiredAccess
        0,//dwShareMode
        NULL,//LPSecurity
        CREATE_NEW| OPEN_EXISTING,//dwCreationDisposition
        0,//Flags and attributes
        NULL);//hTemplateFile

    if (hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("CreateFile failed with the error %d.\n", GetLastError());
        scanf_s("%d", &l);
        return 1;
    }


    success = GetCommState(hPort, &dcb);

    if (!success) {
        printf("GetCommState failed with the error %d.\n ", GetLastError());
        scanf_s("%d", &l);
        return 2;
    }

    success = SetCommState(hPort, &dcb);
    if (!success) {
        printf("SetCommState failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
        scanf_s("%d", &l);
        return 3;
    }
    /*TIME TO READ STUFF*/
        while (GetCommState(hPort, &dcb)) {
        printf("We're in the while statement\n");
         //+=+=+=+=+=+POSSIBLE PROBLEM?
                 if (ReadFile(hPort, buffer, 39, &dwBytesRead, NULL))     {
    //hFile,lpBuffer,NumberofBytesToRead,LPnumberofbytestoread,lpOverlapped
                printf("We're in the ifReadFile Statement!\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(buffer); j++) {
                printf("in the for loop!\n");
                printf("%c", buffer[j]);

            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (!ReadFile(hPort, &buffer, 39, &dwBytesRead, NULL)) {
            printf("Error with ReadFile %d\n.", GetLastError());
        }

    }

    scanf_s("%d", &l);
    CloseHandle(hPort);


    return 0;
    }
    void printCommState(DCB d) {
        printf("\nBaudRate:  %d\tByteSize:  %d\tParity:  %d\tStopBits:  %d\n",
            d.BaudRate,
            d.ByteSize,
            d.Parity,
            d.StopBits);
    }`

Comment: Your `#include`s are fishy BTW.

Comment: *"The program seems to hang during ReadFile, so maybe there's an issue with permissions..."* - If you lack permissions, `ReadFile` will return an error code immediately. Where did you read, that missing permissions would cause arbitrary code to hang?

Comment: It seems you are reading the status of the port via `GetCommState()` and then setting what you read via `SetCommState()` without any modification. Is it really what you want to do?

Comment: My guess is that the IDE serial monitor will set the speed to correct value while your program doesn't, so communication succeeds only after opening the monitor. (currently not posting as answer because I'm not sure)

Comment: Is it what you want to do to throw what is read via second `ReadFile` away?

Comment: MichaelWalz I had to edit them out because stack overflow wasn't allowing them through.
IInspectable I didn't know that, I was only speculating

Comment: @MikeCAT How do I set the correct speed value?  I set the arduino's baudvalue at 9600 and uploaded it.  And yes, the second readfile is there for debugging, but the program never gets there.  I'm using GetCommState to make sure there is still a device there.  If there's a better function let me know!

Comment: C or C++? Your `main` function looks like C++, but the code reads like C. Please pick one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry to ask such a primitive question but what about this would be different if it were in c++?  It was intentionally c

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. I've re-tagged it as C. Your main though is wrong. Should be `int main(void)`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan   Well thank you for that, though that doesn't exactly solve my problem.  The reason I tagged it as c++ is because the languages are similar ( at least at this beginner level ) and I figured I could attract a broader audience of people who could help me.

Comment: Mostly just attracts irritation. Stick to one language. Or none. This isn't actually language specific at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well that's not what I meant to do.  Any chance you could assist me with my problem?

Comment: @MikeCAT You were totally right and it was only until after I truly dissected what I wrote did I find out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the GetCommState line of the code

[GetCommState code function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363260(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here we have it setting the DCB to the settings returned by that function, so by adding another DCB (dcbRecieving, for instance as an example ) just as an error-catching device and having GetCommState point to that other DCB, we can keep our error catching DCB and set our original to the other one, or set the new parameters after the if statement.

Anyways, thanks a ton!